# Dataset for Vehicle Parameters in different weather scenarios

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, cars

I need the a dataset containing the vehicle parameters (such as speed and velocity) that are driven by an actual driver. The data should have various weather conditions such as snow, rain, fog etc. Thanks in advance.